# IntelliJ: Change access modifier for list of vars

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring, shortcut, access-modifiers

Noob programmer here. I'm reorganizing a bunch of the code for a small crappy videogame I'm making right now in LibGDX. I'm moving a bunch of vars from a class that were declared as private into a separate class. I tried to lookup a quick way that I could change all of the vars from private to public all at once, but alas no luck. I can click on each individual var and wait for the lightbulb to show up so that I can click "change access modifier", but it'd be really nice if there were a way to highlight all of them at once and change them all to public. Bonus points if I can change them all to public and static at the same time. (I know that having a class of nothing but public static non-final vars is supposed to be frowned upon, but whatever, it makes things a heck of a lot cleaner! Don't judge me!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create the search and replace template ie like follows:
[image]

then create an inspeciton from it, run and press the "replace all" button:
[image]

For more info please see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html#structural_replace

Comment: Thanks very much for that help. Despite my best efforts, I find myself spending more time tinkering around with the arrangement of things than actually creating new things. OCD is an overused term nowadays, but when it comes to code, I really am OCD. I want everything arranged exactly how I like it. As such, I find myself moving variables from one class to another in for organization's sake. Shortcuts like this help tremendously!